# Как из функции создать глобальную переменную или объект?

Tags: delphi

Я хочу при вызове функции создать `Player: TPlayer;`  record или class,

но что б он оставался после завершения функции, до тех пор пока я его не уничтожу

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: если вы создадите экземпляр класса. то он в принципе никуда не исчезнет, пока вы его не уничтожите вручную.  в случае с записью имеет место быть область видимости. Следует также подумать об использовании глобальных переменных, ибо это не очень хорошая практика. Делфи сам по себе немного пренебрегает  этим в угоду начинающим, так что всегда имеются переменные вида `form1`.

Comment: если в функцие создам Player: TPlayer; TPlayer = class вызвав его конструктор, то до тех пор пока я не вызову Destroy, Player будет существовать? глобально? я смогу вызывать его из других функций в других юнитах?

Comment: да, если у вас будет соответствующая глобальная переменная, которой вы присвоите значение после создания экземпляра класса. То есть если вы опишите переменную `player: TPlayer` в `interface`-секции юнита, а инициализируете ее в своей функции, то потом сможете использовать ее везде, пока не уничтожите.

Comment: interface ... var Player: TPlayer; implementation... так? а как быть с множеством клиентов?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 кто такие "клиенты" - в контексте Вашего вопроса?

Comment: моё приложение сервер, к нему подключаются клиенты, у которых есть параметры запроса и параметры для ответа, я это все храню в TPlayer. Раньше работало так: запрос клиента, парсинг запроса, присваивал значения из запроса, читал из базы предыдущие значения ответа, делал вычисления для нового ответа, сохранял в базу, а потом отвечал. Теперь я хочу сделать чтение из базы при авторизации, держать все в памяти, в переменой TPlayer, до отключения клиента, а в базу только сохранять.

Comment: Но так как клиентов много и они в отдельных потоках, мне нужно их (TPlayer) создать динамически но независимыми друг от друга, что б не было конфликта одновременного обращения двух потоков

Comment: Используйте массив TPlayer. В массиве храните пару - идентификатор клиента и объект TPlayer. Таким образом, каждому клиенту вы будете держать его экземпляр данных. Массив можно динамически дополнять.

Comment: @Kromster а идентифицировать только циклом перебирая весь список на совпадение? нет более быстрого способа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте класс типа ТМенеджерИгроков
В классе - поле со списком клиентов-игроков
Также методы для работы (добавление клиента, удаление, и т.п.)
При старте приложения создайте объект ТМенеджерИгроков
Далее пользуйтесь его методами
При добавлении клиента - создавайте TPlayer и добавляйте пару клиент-TPlayer в список
При удалении клиента - убирайте

Comment: а разве обращение к списку из нескольких потоков не будут вызывать конфликты?

Comment: для обращения к списку из idTcpServer.OnExecute, будет достаточно Критической Секции?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 вы не говорили про потоки в вопросе. Крит.секции будет достаточно, при ее правильном использовании.

Comment: Вы не подскажете способ идентификации нужного мне Player из TList,  если Player.Name уникально,  без перебора всех существующих

Comment: 1 уровень - не занимайтесь микро-оптимизациями. Простой перебор вполне сойдет. 2 уровень - поддерживайте сортировку в списке, тогда сможете использовать бинарный поиск. 3 уровень - TDictionary<string,TPlayer> (емнип).

Comment: критическую секцию можно использовать вне Execute? к примеру создам функцию для чтения, а в ней обращение будет в критической секции

Comment: @ArtGrek13 критическую секцию можно использовать везде где угодно. Она - самостоятельный объект.